# How to make copied SVGs as clear as they are displayed?

Tags: svg, scale

I'm displaying SVGs in `<img>` tags. With `viewBox` these images could be scaled without losing clarity. However, when I copy these images (and paste them into PowerPoint, etc.), they won't be as clear as they are displayed.

How could I make copied images clear? And could this be done without using a canvas?

Example SVG markup:

```html
<svg id="mol-638318-0540814976"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="84" height="40" viewBox="0 0 84 40">
    <style>
        #mol-638318-0540814976 text {
            dominant-baseline: central;
            text-anchor: middle;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: serif;
            fill: black;
        }
        #mol-638318-0540814976 line {
            stroke: black;
        }
    </style>
    <text x="26" y="20">C</text>
    <text x="58" y="20">C</text>
    <line x1="32" y1="20" x2="52" y2="20"></line>
</svg>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably, the svgs are converted to raster/pixel images while pasting. Try to insert them using the original svg file. If powerpoint still renders them in lower resolution - check your svg code for advanced features like filters. Powerpoints svg parser might not support them and thus convert svg to e.g png. It'll help to see your svg markup.

Comment: @herrstrietzel Added markup. Actually I use `<img>` because I didn't find out how to copy the original SVG when it's directly written in HTML. Thanks!